# How to get div ref once it become available in react so it can be used in custom hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following logic for both my main component and custom hook. The issue is that the ref is always null. How can I make the useEffect run again once the div ref becomes available? Technically, the custom hook is running before the div is available, preventing the execution of the logic, or if there is any other way...

```js
// Main component Logic 
const divRefContent = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

// custom hook
useResizeAfterRedirect(divRefContent);

<StyledAppContent id='content' ref={divRefContent}>
// Content
</StyledAppContent>

// Custom hook Logic 
useEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current) {
       divRef.current.style.minHeight = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
     }
}, []);
```